# How can I solve the segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have this code and I don't know why after, I ask if you want to introduce another student and I say 1 or 0 the program ends and said segmentation fault (core dumped).

I ask to introduce another student in `_nodo *insertaEnLista`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct actividades
{
  char tipoDeActividad[22];
  char diaDeLaSemana[12];
  char horaDeIncio[8];
  char horaDeFin[8];
};

struct materias
{
   char nombre[30];
   char profesor[30];
   char tipoDeMateria[20];
   struct actividades *actividad;
};

struct alumnos
{
   char nombre[30];
   int cedula;
   int telefono;
   struct materias *materia;
   struct alumnos *siguiente;
};

typedef struct alumnos _nodo;

_nodo *crearLista(_nodo *apuntador);
bool listaVacia(_nodo *apuntador);
_nodo *insetarEnLista(char nombre[], long  cedula, long  telefono, _nodo *apuntador);
void imprimirLista (_nodo *apuntador);
_nodo *crearNodo(char nombre[], long int cedula, long int telefono);

//AQUI SE CREA LISTA Y SE PONE PARA QUE APUNTE A NULL
_nodo *crearLista(_nodo *apuntador)
{
    return (apuntador = NULL);
}

//ESTA FUNCION VERIFICA SI LA LISTA ESTA VACIA 
bool listaVacia(_nodo *apuntador)
{
    if (apuntador == NULL)
        return (true);
    else
        return (false);
}

//AQUI SE CREA EL NUEVO NODO DE LA LISTA

_nodo *crearNodo(char nombre[], long cedula, long telefono)
{
    _nodo *registroNuevo;

    registroNuevo = (_nodo *) malloc(sizeof(_nodo));

    printf("\n----NUEVO ELEMENTO----\n");
    printf("NOMBRE: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nombre);
    printf("CEDULA: ");
    fflush(stdin);  
    scanf("%ld", &cedula);
    printf("TELEFONO: ");
    fflush(stdin);  
    scanf("%ld", &telefono);
    fflush(stdin);

        strcpy(registroNuevo->nombre, nombre);
        registroNuevo->cedula = cedula;
        registroNuevo->telefono = telefono;
        registroNuevo->siguiente = NULL;

    return registroNuevo;   

}

//AQUI SE INSERTA EL NODO EN LA LISTA LUGEO DE SER CREADO POR LA FUNCION crearNodo
_nodo *insetarEnLista(char nombre[], long  cedula, long  telefono, _nodo *apuntador)
{
    _nodo *registroNuevo, *apuntadorAuxiliar;
    char respuesta,ch;

    do
    {

            registroNuevo=crearNodo(nombre, cedula, telefono);
            if (listaVacia(apuntador)) apuntador = registroNuevo;
            else
            {
                apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;
                while (apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente != NULL)
                    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
                apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = registroNuevo;
            }

            printf("\nPARA INGRESAR A OTRO ALUMNO MARQUE... 1");
            printf("\nPARA SALIR MARQUE... '0'\n");         
     while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');      

    scanf("%c", &respuesta);
        fflush(stdin);
   printf("RESPUESTA = %c", respuesta);             

    }while (strcmp(&respuesta, "1")==0);
    return apuntador;
}

//IMPRIMIR LOS NODOS DE LA LISTA
void imprimirLista (_nodo *apuntador)
{
    _nodo *apuntadorAuxiliar;

    apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

    if (apuntador == NULL)
        printf("NO HAY ELEMENTOS EN LA LISTA \n");
    else
    {
        while(apuntador != NULL)
        {
            printf(" \n------------NODO-------------- ");
            printf("\nNOMBRE: %s \n\n", apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre);
            printf("\n\nCEDULA: %d \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->cedula);
            printf("\nTELEFONO: %d \n", apuntadorAuxiliar->telefono);

            apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    /*printf("INTRODUZCA LOS NUMEROS DE CEDULA QUE DESEA IMPRIMIR \n");*/

    _nodo *inicioLista;
    int cedula;
    int telefono;

    char nombre[20];

    inicioLista = crearLista(inicioLista);

    inicioLista = insetarEnLista(nombre, cedula, telefono, inicioLista);

    imprimirLista(inicioLista);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should step through the code in a debugger and look at the variables at each step to determine the line of code that is causing the issue.

Here is one issue, there may be others.

In this line

```
}while (strcmp(&respuesta, "1")==0);
```

you are using `strcmp` with a variable (`respuesta`) that contains a single character. `strcmp` is expecting a null terminated string (an array of characters with a zero byte at the end). As you may not have a zero byte after the variable, this may cause strcmp to read memory that it shouldn't (this is a buffer overrun)

Much simpler to just use:

```
}while (respuesta == '1');
```